# functional equation, how to solve

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Suppose $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $F,G: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.
$$F(x, y) = \frac{x\circ Ay}{x^TAy}$$
$$G(x, y) = \frac{x\circ By}{x^TBy}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some matrices, $\circ$ is component-wise product ([Hadamar product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product)).
My question is how to build (find) functions $F^{1/2}$ and $G^{1/2}$ such that given $x_2=F(x_0, y_0)$, and $y_2 = G(y_0, x_0)$:
$$x_1 = F^{1/2}(x_0, y_0), y_1=G^{1/2}(y_0, x_0)$$
$$x_2 = F^{1/2}(x_1, y_1), y_2 = G^{1/2}(y_1, x_1)$$

EDIT: got rid of primes.

Comment: what is the prime for ?

Comment: I got rid of primes, because it is confusing.